# socket.io or "raw" sockets for an ionic 3 application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ionic-framework, socket.io, apache-cordova

I am building an Ionic app and I am wondering if all Android/iOS devices will support Websockets or some kind of fallback (as socket.io offers) is necessary?

Comment: Hi! I am pretty sure that you will not have problems using websockets with ionic.

Comment: Take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to improve your question.

Comment: Have you done some research on the topic? have you tried to see the earliest Android version that supports Websockets on official Android Developers portal?

Comment: Yes I did. Websockets are available since 4.4.4 (iirc). I was wondering if this information is only true for native browsers, i can not see why Websockets as a concept would not be possible on those platforms since Websockets are simlpy a TCP based protocol?